# How to prevent Next JS 13 from preloading?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

in my app i've connected to firebase, and whenever a page loads my usage count exceeds due to Next JS preloading feature. and this will cause for unwanted cost. How can I prevent Next JS 13 from preloading. i think this is happening b/c whenever i use `link` of next link it log a warning. and i think when it preloads it call a server.

`The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate 'as' value and it is preloaded intentionally.`

when i run a page with 3 docs fetched from firestore it is logged 8 times and whenever i switch to other tab and back it logs 8 more times without refreshing the page.

so how can i prevent it from preloading?

Answer (score 0):

In next every Link component will preload by default. This usually creates unexpected behavior and performance issues. I think it should have been `prefetch={false}` by default but it's true. In order to prevent Next from preloading you need to use `prefetch={false}`

```
<Link prefetch={false}
      href={`/p${product.slug}`}
      className="flex-grow h-full flex items-center justify-center">
    .....
</Link>
```

Comment: yes i did that and it didn't do anything